# non-static method cannot be referenced confusion

Tags: java, static, non-static

Receiving a non-static method cannot be referenced from static context.  In this example I deleted all of the extra "stuff."  All of the other examples I found had a lot of distractors that confused me.
This is for studying for a final and is NOT part of an assignment.

I do not understand why there is an issue here - troubles understanding static/non-static issue altogether.

In this case all I expect is for 5207 to be the output.

```
package testcase;

public class Testcase {

int number = 5207;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //int number = 5207;
    int div;
    div = divisor(number);
    System.out.println(div);
}

private int divisor(int num){

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to become a `static`  method like this:

```
  private static  int divisor(int num){
   return number;
   }
```

Or instance the object of class `Testcase` :

```
 Testcase tsc = new Testcase();
 div = tsc.divisor(number);
```

Comment: The first one wont work since number is a non static variable.